# Win32com not dispatching excel, saying 'Server execution failed'

Tags: python, excel, win32com

My initial script is:

```
import win32com.client
import os

file1= r'C:\\Users\cevans\Desktop\models1\file.xlsm'

def refresher():
    if os.path.exists(file1):
        xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=file1,ReadOnly=1)
        xl.Visible = True
        xl.Application.Run('Report_Tablerefresh1')
        xl.Workbooks(1).Close(SaveChanges=1)
        xl.Application.Quit()
        del xl
refresher()
```

I am getting this error when trying to do a simple dispatch of excel, oddly the script had been running fine for a few weeks then this error popped up. Any suggestions?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "C:/Users/cevans/PycharmProjects/RigLocatorMapPull/Pipe_StorageRefresh.py",     line 17, in <module>
    refresher()
  File     "C:/Users/cevans/PycharmProjects/RigLocatorMapPull/Pipe_StorageRefresh.py", l    ine 10, in refresher
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 104, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 84, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2146959355, 'Server execution failed', None, None)
```

Comment: My first guess is it has to do with excel specifically as I have tested with Word and other applications and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution was to reboot windows OS (doing complete reinstall) as there appeared to be an error with the windows OS registry with excel. I found this to be the cause of other 'Server Execution Failed' type errors with using win32com.